# What next after ADO.net

Tags: ado.net

I have been using ADO.net since 2002/2003 and most of the application I have developed so far use ADO.net (I do use business objects in my application but underlying data access is through ADO.net)

Question: What is/will be next paradigm of data access technology assuming you are using .net framework and SQL Server?

I am hearing LINQ and Entity Framework but not sure about LINQ or at least its future?

Any advice along with a recommended book will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object relational mapping is perhaps the next paradigm for data access technology after ADO.NET, although you could say that its already pretty well established. Although Entity Framework is still fairly new NHibernate has been around for several years, and its Java predecessor since 2001.

If you are looking for a good book about NHibernate and object relational mapping in general then [NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/) is good. Its very readable and the first chapter, which is available as a free sample, covers the rationale behind ORM as well as comparisons between NHibernate and other technologies like LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is here to stay, what I think you are referring to is LINQ to SQL which while not being very actively developed by Microsoft, is still alive however Microsoft are making it fairly clear that EF is the future.